# Vue 2 - v-for looping through an array of objects gives different results

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2

I have a component, with a template where I loop through an array of objects, that looks like this:

```
"value": [
     {"list_item": "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus"},
     {"list_item": "Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas"},
     {"list_item": "Autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui"},
     {"list_item": "Lorem ipsum dolor"}
]
```

This is the part where I loop through the array in the template:

```
 <ul v-for="argument of content.list.value">
   <li><i class="material-icons">check</i> {{ argument.list_item !== 'undefined' ? argument.list_item : argument.list-text }}</li>
 </ul>
```

And that works fine when I am sending data from one component, but when I try to send it from another component, where the array of objects looks like this:

```
 "list": [
     {"list-text": "Bare medlemmer ee medlemmer"},
     {"list-text": "Og ikke nok med det....."},
     {"list-text": "de er også virkelige personer"},
     {"list-text": "akkurat som deg og meg"}
  ],
```

I don't get any data displayed. On testing in the template, where I just displayed the whole object:

```
<ul v-for="argument of content.list.value">
   <li><i class="material-icons">check</i> {{ argument }}</li>
 </ul>
```

I got this:

```
{ "list-text": "Bare medlemmer ee medlemmer" } 
{ "list-text": "Og ikke nok med det....." } 
{ "list-text": "de er også virkelige personer" } 
{ "list-text": "akkurat som deg og meg" }
```

And if I do `{{ argument.list-text }}` I get:

```
NaN
```

Why can't I display the value of the property in the object?

Comment: Do you mean `typeof argument.list_item !== 'undefined'`? Otherwise, `argument.list_item !== 'undefined'` will always evaluate to true and you will attempt to retrieve the value of the key `list_item` no matter what. Also, `-` is an invalid character to use in dot notation (because it will be evaluated as a mathematical expression, i.e. `argument.list - text`, and since `text` is undefined you get `NaN`), you should refer to it as `{{ argument['list-text'] }}`.

Comment: then I get ```NaN```

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware that I can't use ```-```
 in dot notation, that fixed the whole thing, thank you!

Comment: I'll just add my response as an answer, so that people in the future can see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting `NaN` is because of this expression you are using: `{{ argument.list-text }}`. Note that you cannot use `-` in dot notation, because it will simply evaluated as a mathematical expression, i.e. `argument.list - text`. In this case, since both `argument.list` and `text` is undefined in the scope, you will simply get a "not a number" (NaN) error.

Instead, you will want to use `{{ argument['list-text'] }}`.

p/s: If you want to check if `argument.list_item` is undefined, you can use the following strategies:

- `argument.list_item !== void 0`
- `argument.list_item !== undefined`
- `typeof argument.list_item !== 'undefined'`
- `typeof arugment.list_item !== typeof undefined`